# No segment variables - Zoo Triggers and MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager, structure, segments, zoo-triggers

We running a site which uses MSM and Structure. To get around the 'category' issue in Structure, we've added Zoo triggers, which works great on the `default_site` but not so well in the MSM sites.

In the MSM sites, we're pulling team entries from the master site, but in doing so, we seem to have lost all segment variables.

I've tried `{segment_4}`, `{triggers:cat_name_1}`, `{segment_4_category_id}` (Low seg2cat), `{last_segment_category_id}` (seg2cat), `{triggers:cat_id_1}` and `{triggers:cat_id_last}` and none of them return a value.

The triggers variables just output the tag to screen, but I would have expected the native tag to work in this case, or seg2cat. My guess is the parse order gets borked by the structure/triggers combination, but without segment variables, we're pretty limited in terms of what we can do on the page.

We're running 2.9.0 with the latest version of structure and triggers.

Anyone any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update for Zoo Triggers (1.2.5) released today fixed this issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can access site URLs from another site using MSM. I think it's an EE limitation.

Comment: Thanks Travis :-) We're not trying to access the URLs from one of the other sites, just the segment variables so we can filter on a category. This was a site previously running 2.8 and this seemed to be working fine, so I'm leaning towards an error in Zoo Triggers